# What does the error logging in via JAAS: !role mean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, jaas, maven-jetty-plugin

I have the following Jetty setup:

```
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService">
    <Set name="Name">FOO JAAS Realm</Set>
    <Set name="LoginModuleName">foo</Set>
    <Set name="roleClassNames">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>foo.jaas.principal.UserPrincipal</Item>
            <Item>foo.jaas.principal.RolePrincipal</Item>
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASRole</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</New>
```

I am using an Embedded Jetty 7.6.1.v20120215 via the Maven Jetty Plugin.

When I try to login via the form that I have, the logins fields are properly sent to /j_security_check. I have written my own LoginModule which is invoked and validates the users properly. I can see their principals are properly fetched from the database.

Instead of being shown the secured page, Jetty shows me:

```
HTTP ERROR 403

Problem accessing /foo/auth.html. Reason:

    !role
```

I am not quite sure what it really means by that.

I have the following in my web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ADMINISTRATOR</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/auth.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>foo</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/authfail.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

I am logging in as the administrator.

Any help on the cryptic JAAS message displayed by Jetty would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that is logging in does not have the role ADMINISTRATOR that you enforce on /auth.html.

During the commit phase,your JAAS Login module is expected to add the user roles to the Subject Principals. The roles are held in a class extending Principal which you indicate to Jetty in the jetty.xml file.

You login module should have something like this in `commit()`

```
    Set<Principal> subjectPrincipals = subject.getPrincipals();


    //add the roles
    for (String role : userRolesList) {

         subjectPrincipals.add(new RolePrincipal(role));
    }
```

`RolePrincipal`is your role class

Comment: The thing is -- my login module is indeed adding these role principals to the subject. The user does indeed have that principal. Any other hints?

Comment: Sure. Is your realm name exactly matching in jetty-web.xml and in your web.xml (not the case in your code above). What holds your roles ? a JaasRole instance ? Why declare 3 classes in the jetty.xml at 'roleClassNames' ? Did you try to specify debug=true in the login module configuration file and watch the logs ?

Comment: I have my own implementation of a LoginModule and Role. The realm is correct in both the web.xml and jetty setup point to it. I can see that the login module is correctly verifying the users and committing their roles to the subject. The error message appears to mean that the roles are not found somewhere, somehow which is sort of confusing to me.

Comment: Your role is definitely not on the subject. Try removing the security constraint on your webapp to verify that. Also you say you implemented a LoginModule but your conf shows that you are using the JaasLoginService which expects the roles to be held in the  JAASRole class. Is it what you are doing?

Comment: You were right that the role was not on the subject. I will debug this further and let you know the outcome. When I removed the `<auth-constraint/>` it worked. I will get to the bottom of this!

Comment: Hm... after removing the constraint though, it still displays the page even after an unsuccessful login.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and above code was already there....
but after reading: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/JAAS
I had to also update web-jetty.xml and add

```
<Set name="roleClassNames">
   <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>login.RolePrincipal</Item>
   </Array>
</Set>
```

in this section:

```
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService">
```

because I used a custom made principal for roles "login.RolePrincipal" (actually I inherited the code and was moving the app from tomcat to jetty :) )

Comment: Hi Davor, can you send a template for login.RolePrincipal, I am trying to implement the Embedded jetty in my application.